# Dynamic load page with AngularFire and Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am learning Angular2 and converting an app to Angular2. Now I am trying to create dynamicpages that loads the content from Firebase. But I got stuck. If I understand correctly, I need top load AngularFire in the constructor and the routeparms in `ngOnInit()`. Since the constructor is called first, I can't use the router Param to call AngularFire.

This is my code now:

```
export class StaticContentComponent {
    pagename;
    isHome;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            this.pagename = params['pageName'];
            this.isHome = (this.pagename == 'home');
        });
    }

    pagecontent: FirebaseObjectObservable<any[]>;
    constructor(af: AngularFire, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.pagecontent = af.database.object('/pages/content/' +  this.pagename);
    }
}
```

I tried to switch them, use other inits, but big red lines of errors appear in the log.

Also, should I use a service with only AngularFire? I am not sure, the AngularFire examples doesn't use them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply nest the calls.

```
constructor(private af: AngularFire, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        this.pagename = params['pageName'];
        this.isHome = (this.pagename == 'home');

        this.pagecontent = af.database.object('/pages/content/' +  this.pagename);
    });
}
```

This does the following:

1. `subscribe` to the route params
2. after they resolve, retrieve the object from Firebase

EDIT:

For your seconds question, AngularFire itself is a service already, so if the functionality of AF is enough for you, you don't have to wrap it inside another service.

What I like to do is wrap AF in another service and add console debug messages, for example.

Comment: Thnx for the answers. If i try the code i got "af not find" if i add  af: AngularFire; the params can't be read (Cannot read property 'params' of undefined)

Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Comment: I have updated my answer. You forgot to add the `private` keyword before `af: AngularFire`